# Integral probably divergent according to decimal places

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply Newton-Formula to some Inverse-Sampling-Method with length n=500. (u uniform random numbers, Fphi_x our according distribution,fphi_x our density).
Newton-Formula is then: find x, such that Fphi_x(x)-u=0

```
`u=runif(500)
xnewton=rep(1e-30,500)
fphi_x=function(x){return(0.307/(x^{5/12}*(x+1)))} 
Fphi_x=function(u){k=integrate(fphi_x,0,u)$value
               return(k)}
 for(i in 1:500)
{
  while(abs(Fphi_x(xnewton[i])-u[i])>0.0000001){
  xnewton[i]=xnewton[i]-(Fphi_x(xnewton[i])-u[i])/fphi_x(xnewton[i])
  }
 }`
```

The code is correctly. But i got the error code: 
`Error in integrate(fphi_x, 0, u) : the integral is probably divergent.`
I found out:

`Fphi_x(1e15)=1.197390096030634e-05`
but if i have decimal places in it; for example
`Fphi_x(10000000000.000000)` i get the Error Message.
According to my distribution i will defenitly get high numbers, with decimal places e.g. 431232.132131. How to solve that?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that your integrand is infinite at it's lower bound;  that is

```
> fphi_x(0)
[1] Inf
```

Apparently `integrate` can handle this for smaller upper bounds but not larger ones.  I tried a couple of approaches.  One that that seems to work is make a change of variable in your integral

```
      y = 1/x
```

which keeps the integrand finite but makes the upper bound explicitly Infinite.   You can then use the integration function `quadinf` from the `pracma` package which allows infinite bounds on the integral.
To compare results from the two integration routines, `set.seed(100)` is used which fixes the random values returned for `u`.   With these values for `u`, the `integrate` function will handle the first 126 values of `u` while `quadinf` will calculate all 500 values.  The first 126 values for each are the same.
Code for both follows:

```
set.seed(100)
  u=runif(500)
  xnewton=rep(1e-30,500)
  fphi_x=function(x){return(0.307/(x^{5/12}*(x+1)))} 
  Fphi_x=function(u){ k=integrate(fphi_x,0,u)$value
                      return(k)}
  for(i in 1:126)
  {
    while(abs(Fphi_x(xnewton[i])-u[i])>0.0000001){
      xnewton[i]=xnewton[i]-(Fphi_x(xnewton[i])-u[i])/fphi_x(xnewton[i])
    }
  }
  xnewton_x <- xnewton
 #
 #  using change of variable y = 1/x and quadinf function
 #
  library(pracma)
  xnewton=rep(1e-30,500)
  fphi_y <- function(y) .307*y^(5/12-1)/(1+y)
  Fphi_y <- function(u) quadinf(fphi_y, 1/u, Inf)$Q

  for(i in 1:500)
   {
     while(abs(Fphi_y(xnewton[i])-u[i])>0.0000001){
       xnewton[i] <- xnewton[i]- (Fphi_y(xnewton[i]) - u[i])/fphi_x(xnewton[i])
    }
   }
   xnewton_y <- xnewton
```

`quadinf` seems to take a longer to run than `integrate` but at least seems to return results for cases when `integrate` fails.